Error: The certificate for this server is invalid
I am creating an Outlook add-in locally. The react application for the UI makes an api call to a locally deployed flask app for some data. But the react app is never able to get the data from the flask app due to some security issue which I initially thought was because of the CORS error.

Not allowed to request resource


XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:5000/api/generate-email due to access control check

Even with CORS enabled on the flask server, the error didnt change. I also tried adding a self signed certificate in my flask app but then it shows the below errors in the console of Outlook

The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “localhost”, which could put your confidential information at risk


XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:5000/api/generate-email due to access control check


Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “localhost”, which could put your confidential information at risk

There is very limited documentation on the official website. Am I doing something wrong here or is there any other way to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

you need a valid SSL certificate - read this for some helpful information about setting up a secure "localhost"
